# Constraint camera to move with object's bone

Tags: bones, camera, constraints

I have a person and a camera which is looking directly at him from side view. My question is how to set a constraint to move camera with spine bone? The camera should not rotate with bone, just move with the person to keep the side view. I have tried to set camera as the spine's parent but it rotates along. Also, I used child of, transformation, track,... constraints but can't figure out the right way. Another issue is that after setting the parent relation location of camera changes. Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: 1. add an empty in, line it up with your spine, constraint it to the spine with "copy location"; 2. parent your camera to the empty; //now your camera will follow the empty/spine without picking its rotation data.

Comment: thank you. It works but after loading the bvh file for walking, the angle of camera changes. In other words, the camera view is not side view.

Comment: The cause of this problem is that loading bvh changes the rotation value of person and when I include rotation constraint it works well, except that the spine rotation also rotates the camera! Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: add a bone specifically for this camera, make it copy your spine location, that way when you load the bvh file, world location of this bone stays the same. Then you use this special bone for what you were trying to do. I don't know loading bvh will change any bones' rotation but I hope this may help. The key concept is always add a lot of in between things to help delivering the value across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [ChildOf constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html) allows you to parent an object to another with the ability to turn off some of the transformations that are copied.

To have the camera move with the character and allow the head/shoulders to rotate within the camera view, you turn off the rotation options in the constraint. You just need to pick a bone that you want to follow, maybe the shoulders or hips depending on how much of the character you want to move in front of the camera.

When you first choose the bone, the camera may jump out of place, click the Set Inverse button to fix this. You can also move the camera into position after you add the child of constraint

[image: childof constraint]

Here the camera has a ChidOf constrained set to the selected bone, you can see it follows the bottom point of the bone but doesn't rotate with it.

[image: sample animation]